# Parent div with first child dimensions

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the not explicit title, but basically what I want to do is this:

[image]

There would be 2 childs, one of the "text", and another of the red rectangle, and the parent would conserve the "padding" of the "text" child.

I was struggling with "position" rules for a lot of time, any help would be appreciated! thank you!!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

you want something like this???

(next time give some code for that we know exactly what you want and to know what you tried already)

```css
    .parent{
      position:relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: pink;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.red{
    width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  left:225px;
  bottom:-12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div>
<p>
text goes here
</p>
</div>
<div class="red">
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for that, I though it wasn't necesary because anything I've tried didn't work, but your code helped, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: you give code for that we know what you already tried! You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications to DanyCode's code so the red border can be centered on a different way:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.red {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.red-thing {
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <p>text goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="red">
    <div class="red-thing"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the thanks to DanyCode!